# Want to write a loop to find reflectance values for each column

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

So I have this code in R that I'm using on a dataframe df that comes in the format where each row is a wavelength (823 rows/wavelengths) and each column is a pixel (written as V1-V2554).

[image: Image of dataset here.]

I have the code to normalise each reflectance value as such per each spectrum/pixel:

```
# Define function to find vector length
veclen=function(vec) {
    sqrt(sum(vec^2))
}
# Find vector length for spectrum of each pixel
df_vecV6 <- df %>%
              group_by(Wavelength) %>%
              summarise(veclengthV6 =  veclen(V6))
            
# Join new variable "veclength"
df <- df %>%
      left_join(df_vecV6, by = "Wavelength")
            
# Define function that return normalized vector
vecnorm=function(vector) {
          vector/veclen(vector)
}
# Normalize by dividing each reflectance value by the vector’s length
df$refl_normV6 <- vecnorm(df$V6)
```

but I want to create a loop to do this for all 2553 columns. I started writing it but seem to come up with problems. In this case df is finaldatat and I wanted to create a list svec to store vector lengths before the next steps:

```
for(i in (1:ncol(finaldatat))){
  svec[[i]]<- finaldatat %>% 
    #group_by(Wavelength) %>% 
    summarise (x = veclen(finaldatat[,i]))
}
```

That first step runs, but the vector lengths that are meant to be below zero are way above so I already know there's a problem. Any help is appreciated!

Ideally in the final dataframe I would only have the normalised results in the same 2554x824 format.

Comment: Please provide example data by pasting the output of `dput(df)` (or `dput(head(df))`) and don't show a picture of your data, thanks

Comment: A good rule of thumb when writing R code is "If you're thinking of using a loop, there's probably a better way".  This is definitely one such case.  I'd look at the `across` function in `dplyr` or similar options.  See [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html) for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dplyr`'s `across` function to apply `vecnorm` to all columns from `V1` to `V2554`.

```
result <- df %>%
            group_by(Wavelength) %>%
            summarise(across(V1:V2554, vecnorm))
            #In older version of dplyr use summarise_at : 
            summarise_at(vars(V1:V2554), vecnorm)
```